# meaning of "whilf"

Tags: word-meaning

[The new encyclopædia; or, Universal dictionary ofarts and sciences, Volume 23](https://books.google.com/books?id=JiWfH8PBl1wC&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=while+or+whilf&source=bl&ots=XjE7aZf1Zl&sig=GpXf4-k34ThuGw9AfYupgqhYXxM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjensy90-vSAhWHO48KHb2aBZAQ6AEIJzAGhttp://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=13&ved=0ahUKEwjyx6mQ1OvSAhUJvY8KHZnACwQ4ChAWCBwwAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmobile.twitter.com%2Fhashtag%2Fwhilf&usg=AFQjCNGdUbrlxUN-nJLfGydyBytOvlsOug&sig2=KbNKpHUBjnp4Y9sz2ZxHSA)

[Lexical analysis: Deterministic Automata](http://www.idi.ntnu.no/~janchris/tdt4205-sp17/slides02.pdf)

From above link, I found the world "whilf" on Google.
But it is not included in dictionary.What does 'whilf' mean?

Answer (score 1):

'Whilf' is not a word in English. Your 'lexical analysis' link shows 'Whilf' as a variable in a computer programming language. Those sort of variables can be defined or set as any arbitrary string of characters; I could create program variables called 'xxxxxyx' or 'jifvbabhb2', and neither of those are English words either.